# How to handle popup links in CefSharp

Tags: winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am creating a tabbed web browser using `CefSharp 39.0.2`. Right now, if the user clicks on a link on a website, it will open a new window that has none of my original UI. For example, when you click on an article link on Google News, it opens in a new window, but without any of the browsing controls I have made up. I also looked into the `Cef.WinForms.Example` program, and it does the same exact thing.

Is it possible to handle this in a different way? I would like for the link to either open in a new tab, or open in a new window (with all the controls there). I have been looking through the GitHub issues, and I could not find anything like this (maybe I was not looking hard enough, because I would think this is what others want to do as well...). I looked through all the `events` for the browser control, and I could not find any that would seem like they handle it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ChromiumWebBrowser` has a `LifeSpanHandler` property. To manually control popup windows in Cefsharp, you have to implement your own life span handler object implementing the `ILifeSpanHandle` interface.

Every time browser wants to open a new window, it will call your life span handler's `OnBeforePopup` function. Here you can implement your desired behavior. If you return `false`, browser will pop up a new window. If you return `true`, browser will ignore pop up action, but you can manually create your new window, new tab, etc...

This is a very simple example of custom life span hander. On popup request, it fires an event called PopupRequest. You can subscribe such event and create new window/tab manually. Then, it returns true that instructs `ChromiumWebBrowser` not to create its own new window. However, you need to implement creating new window with another `ChromiumWebBrowser` on your own.

```
public class SampleLifeSpanHandler: ILifeSpanHandler
{
    public event Action<string> PopupRequest;

    public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser browser, string sourceUrl, string targetUrl, ref int x, ref int y, ref int width,
        ref int height)
    {
        if (PopupRequest != null)
            PopupRequest(targetUrl);

        return true;
    }

    public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser browser)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The LifeSpanHandler Property is hidded on editor by default. You must to write manually on editor (without intellisense).