# CefSharp BrowserControl - Image Hyperlinks open in new Form

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Hope somebody could give me some advice or point me into some direction.

Im using CefSharp Browser Control in an application, one if the things that im struggling with is when i click on Image Hyperlinks (or any hyperlinks for that matter) it shows a Windows Form where the image is displayed, i fiddled around in the RequestHandler on the OnBeforeBrowse method and added the following:

```
if (ValidateURL(request.Url))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(request.Url);
                return true;
            }

        return false;
```

Where the ValidateURL does some REGEX checks.

What i have noticed is that a Windows Form (Blank Windows Form) still opens up and the image on my Browser (expected).

Where can i double check to not show the blank Windows Form, or hide it?

Version:
Chromium 39.0.2171.95 CEF: r2069, CefSharp: 39.0.2.0

Regards
Jean

Comment: Please update to include version.

Comment: It seems that it happens when you click on an image that is going to be opened in a new window - you might use LifeSpanHandler and OnBeforeBrowse instead - it has been already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553577/how-to-handle-popup-links-in-cefsharp/30557700#30557700