# Open Links containing pattern in different tab in CefSharp WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have an application with two tabs in a tab control, each containing a CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser. Let's call these ChromiumWebBrowsers `searchBrowser` and `detailsBrowser`.

Let's say I click a link in `searchBrowser`, and if that link contains the text "xrep2", I want the link to be opened in `detailsBrowser`, else it should be opened in `searchBrowser`.

In a previous version of this application, I used the WinForms web browser control. I'm rewriting the app in WPF and using CefSharp. with the WinForms it was quite simple. In the `Navigating` event, you do something like

```
private void browser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (browser.StatusText.Contains("xrep2."))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        detailsBrowser.Url = new Uri(browser.StatusText);
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

But when using CefSharp, it appears I have to create an event inside a LifeSpanHandler per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553577/how-to-handle-popup-links-in-cefsharp) with an event that fires when a `target="_blank"` link is clicked. I'm not super comfortable creating and subscribing to custom events, so I'd like to find an easier way to do this, but if not, I need to figure out how to subscribe a method to the event created by `public event Action<string> PopupRequest;` and where to put the logic (something like `if(searchBrowser.Address.Contains("xrep2")) detailsBrowser.Address = X else searchBrowser.Address = X`

I have the LifeSpanHandler class code below, including the PopupRequest event that is supposed to fire when a `target="_blank"` link is clicked, but I'm stuck at this point.

```
public class LifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
{
    public event Action<string> PopupRequest;

    public virtual bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser browserControl, string sourceUrl, string targetUrl, ref int x, ref int y, ref int width,
        ref int height)
    {
        if (PopupRequest != null)
            PopupRequest(targetUrl);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your logic in the OnBeforePopup method, get that working, then move to getting an event working if required. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/RequestEventHandler/RequestEventHandler.cs for example of a Request Handler that publishes events

Comment: So between `if (PopupRequest != null) PopupRequest(targetUrl);` and `return true`? What does `PopupRequest(targetUrl)` do if the OnBeforePopup method is called by the event?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Look at the OnBeforeBrowse method in the link I've provided for an example of returning a result from an event.